# Array to string conversion error shop

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to create a "details page" for my website, using PHP. It connects properly, but when I try to insert the images and details, it comes up with an array to string error

```
<div id="main">
  <section class="products">
  <?php
  if(isset($_GET["view_product"])) {

  ?>
<div class="product_ind">
<div class="image">

    </div>
<div class="image_details">
```

trying to put my ProductName ProductPrice and Image here^^

As you can see, I have connected it here, but the `$row` thing doesn't work above.

```
$sql = "SELECT * from product";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
   // output data of each row
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
<div class="product-card"> 
 <a href="./shop.php?view_product=<?php echo $row["ProductID"]?>"><img src="images/<?php echo $row["ProductImage"];?>"height="250" width="200"></img>
   <div class="product-info">
  <p><?php echo $row["ProductName"];?> $<?php echo $row["ProductPrice"];?>    </p>
    </div>
   </a>

   </div>

   <?php  
    }
    }
   }
  ?>
 </div>
 </section>
 </div>
```

Comment: `<?php print_r['ProductName'] ?>` - what is this?

Comment: Check `<?php print_r['ProductName']` line!!

Comment: i dont know!!!! im trying to insert my data base link things in the image_details div

Comment: Note that the `img` tag is a selfclosing tag, thus should be used like this `<img src="path/to/img" />` and not like this `<img src="path/to/img"></img>`...

Answer (score 0):

print_r is a function, not an array, therefore you have a syntax error. Remove that debugging p tag:

```
<div id="main">
  <section class="products">
  <?php
  if(isset($_GET["view_product"])) {

  ?>
<div class="product_ind">
<div class="image">

    </div>
<div class="image_details">
</div>
</div>
<?php
}
else {
$sql = "SELECT * from product";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
   // output data of each row
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
<div class="product-card"> 
 <a href="./shop.php?view_product=<?php echo $row["ProductID"]?>"><img           src="images/<?php echo $row["ProductImage"];?>"height="250" width="200"></img>
   <div class="product-info">
  <p><?php echo $row["ProductName"];?> $<?php echo $row["ProductPrice"];?>    </p>
    </div>
   </a>

   </div>

   <?php  
    }
    }
   }
  ?>
 </div>
 </section>
 </div>
```

Comment: yeah ive been messing around with that part of the code to try and make it work. i have made an edit but i still dont know how to insert my ProductName ProductPrice and Image

Comment: @PaigeWalker, do you have a ProductName and a ProductPrice column in your product table?

Comment: yes i do. im not very experienced in php as my teacher doesnt teach us and i have to teach myself....

Comment: @PaigeWalker, if you put an echo "foo"; just after if ($result->num_rows > 0) { is it displayed?